# Stellar Aberration

Tags: special-relativity, optics, astrophysics

In Stellar Aberration Experiment how do I know there is a star above my head before doing the experiment?

Reference: Special Theory of Relativity - Resnick (Section-1.7)

Comment: Because you see it before you start moving!

Comment: In that case if an observer rotates around a source of light which is “overhead” its (source’s) actual position is always the same. In that case, if the moving observer is inertial, he can know actual position of the source because there is aberration of light but no aberration of forces. https://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath562/kmath562.htm